# Does textarea have default maxlength for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am trying to set the .value of my text area to a certain string that is very long. It works fine on other browsers,  but on Firefox, the whole string does not show up in the textarea. I am aware that there is a maxlength attribute. I did not set this. If it is not set, is there a default value or is it unlimited?

Comment: The specification says that when the maxlength property is not set, a textarea accepts an unlimited amount of characters.

Comment: i know chrome and firefox both get slow after pasting >1mb into the textarea. i've used 8mb before, but it took a couple "unresponsive script" click-throughs to get it to sink in...

Comment: If the length exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` you'll probably run into the crashing-the-browser due to range errors stage, but that's about 8 pebibytes on my system so you'd be out of memory way before then

Comment: Please show us a fiddle reproducing this issue.

Comment: So it turns out that the DOMParser().parseFromString function that I was using was breaking up the text into multiple text nodes with a limit of 4096 characters. After this line of code I used the [normalize()](http://osdir.com/ml/mozilla.devel.dom/2006-08/msg00041.html) function before passing this string to my textarea. This seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

**No.** From Mozilla: ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea))

> **maxlength**:
>   The maximum number of characters (Unicode code points) that the user can enter. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters.

Comment: that's not an answer to the question (op says " I am aware that there is a maxlength attribute"). a simple "no" suffices...

Comment: @dandavis OP was asking if Firefox has *default* maxlength value.